# Как создать отдельные файлы в формате mbox для всех коммитов конкретной ветки одной командой в git?

Tags: git

Согласно [официальной документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), чтобы создать файл в формате `mbox`, который будет иметь расширение `*.patch`, для конкретного коммита, необходимо выполнить команду:

```
git format-patch -1 <хэш-коммита>
```

Тоже условие, только для трёх последник коммитов:

```
git format-patch -3
```

Далее читаем официальную документацию, где сказано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот у меня есть ветка, в которой есть 3 коммита. Я ввожу команду `git format-patch`, которая, судя по скрину выше, должна создать для каждого коммита свой файл в формате `mbox`, но при выполнении данной команды **не создается ни одного файла**, почему?

Comment: Вы забыли указать аргумент указывающий для каких коммитов создать файлы, а значит будет взято 0 коммитов и для них будет создано 0 файлов

Comment: @andreymal, правильно ли я понял, что **обязательно** нужно указывать количество аргументов? Почему тогда в документации указано, что команда `git format-patch` обернёт **каждый** коммит?

Comment: Потому что, вероятно, авторы надеялись, что вы сами по контексту догадаетесь, что имеется в виду оборачивание каждого **указанного вами** коммита. Кроме того, в английском оригинале написано «each commit», но не «every commit»

Comment: @andreymal, странно они надеялись :) Each и every имеют один и тот же смысл, но
**Each** употребляется когда речь идет о двух и более предметах или вещах, **Every** – когда речь идет о трех и более предметах или вещах.

Comment: Странно вас обучали английскому, each и every имеют очень разный смысл. Ну да ладно, в любом случае для format-patch нужно указать аргумент. Если хотите патчи для **вообще каждого** коммита, можно указать `--root`